# Errors generating Enterprise.jar using wsdlc

Tags: soap-api, wsdl, enterprise-wsdl, com.force.api

Running through the tutorial on the developer site gets me errors.

```
C:\Users\z\Downloads>java -classpath C:\Users\z\Downloads\force-wsc-
39.0.1.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc C:\Users\z\Downloads\wsdl.jsp.xml C:\
Users\z\Downloads\enterprise2.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/stringtemplate/v4
/STGroupDir
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544
)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroupDir
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

I've tried every trick I could find including putting the folder into the classpath. I'm not 100% sure I dled the enterprise wsdl correctly. when I click the generate link it opened as a new tab in chrome in which I save as 
wsdl.jsp.xml and renamed as wsdl.

Any tips or hints would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a Java library (JAR file) versioning problem where one class expects to find another class but can't. Check these [Google results](https://www.google.ie/search?q=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%3A+org%2Fstringtemplate%2Fv4+%2FSTGroupDir&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIE720IE720&oq=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%3A+org%2Fstringtemplate%2Fv4+%2FSTGroupDir&aqs=chrome..69i57.453j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out. the issue was that I didn't get the uber.jar which is pretty confusing because I couldn't find it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-wsc/39.0.1)

Ended up getting it from here. Works fine.
http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/force/api/force-wsc/39.0.1/